# How to make Style with app prefix in CardView

Tags: android, xml

I have some code of line in this code may use content padding because android:padding attribute not working but content padding properly work and also android:elevation is provide support above 21 API so may use cardElevation but this app XML namspace prefix using how to make style of cardView?

**Gradle Dependency :**

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'
```

**Code :**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_margin="5dp" 
    app:contentPadding="5dp" 
    app:cardElevation="3dp">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="ABC" /> 

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Have you added xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"?

Comment: yes @Mr.Rabbit but when making style then

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please rephrase it.

Comment: @Mr.Rabbit problem solve, your suggested name space by default android added when style calling when app prefix into style